# create new objects using for loop but linking objects through constructors

Tags: loops, object, for-loop

I am trying to create a for-loop to do the following. The road class has a constructor that
basically links all the new objects together.  I want to create a for loop to do this so I can create more roads, like 50.

```
Road r3 = new Road();
Road r2 = new Road(r3);
Road r1 = new Road(r2);
```

Comment: You don't mention what language you're using, which will make it harder for people to answer fully.

Answer (score 2):

```
    int count = 50;
    Road prev = null;
    for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
      prev = new Road(prev);
    }
```

Comment: @PeteBel Who said anything about Java?

Comment: @JaredNielsen The objects will still exist because the constructor of each new object saves a reference to the previous. At the end of the loop, `prev` points to the end of a linked list of `Road` objects.

Comment: that does work. actually it seemed like it didnt. sorry about me not knowing. this helps me. Im really a beginner trying to learn things. Really appreciate your replies.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some kind of collection, such as an array. The exact implementation and syntax depend of the language you're using.

When you have an array, you can loop over it, and for each item (at index `i`) create the next item (at index `i+1`).

Answer (score 0):

```
Road road = new Road(); //first unlinked road

ArrayList<Road> roads = new ArrayList<Road>(); 
roads.add(road); //adds first Road

for(int i = 0; i < 49; i++) {
    roads.add(new Road(roads.get(i))); //adds other Roads with reference to last road in ArrayList
}
```